# Как и в прошлом году. Запятая

Tags: пунктуация

В предложениях: 1)Оздоровительный лагерь "Ромашка" с круглосуточным пребыванием детей как и в прошлом году будет работать в 3 смены с общим охватом 150 детей.2) Как и в прошлые годы планируем 100-процентную занятость детей, состоящих на КДН и ПДН и на внутришкольном контроле. Нужно ли выделить запятыми "как и в прошлом году", нужна ли запятая во втором предложении перед вторым "и".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Оздоровительный лагерь "Ромашка" с круглосуточным пребыванием детей, как и в прошлом году, будет работать в 3 смены с общим охватом 150 детей.

2) Как и в прошлые годы, планируем 100-процентную занятость детей, состоящих на КДН и ПДН и на внутришкольном контроле.

Пояснение

1) Оборот с союзом КАК И всегда обособляется.

2) Здесь нет повторяющего ся союза И...И, первый союз связывает два первых обстоятельства, а второй присоединяет к ним третье обстоятельство.

Comment: Я Вам очень-очень благодарна.